# "premier-league" - Ambiguous Tag Usage

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[posdef](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/364/posdef) introduced a [premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premier-league) tag, regarding the English Premier League of the UEFA, in the following [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/what-factors-could-be-accounted-for-liverpool-fcs-lack-of-success-in-epl-in-the).

Although legit, there appears to be an [Indian Premier League](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/how-are-ipl-players-paid) in cricket. In addition, there seem to be many [premier leagues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League_(disambiguation)) in existence.

**Should we define this tag by the full league name ([english-premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-premier-league) or [epl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epl)), by its confederation ([uefa](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uefa)), by international governing body ([fifa](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa)), or leave as is?**

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking here, can you clarify this? There are many Football leagues in English football, 'The Premiership' is the top level. The IPL (Indian Premier League) is in Cricket, a completely different sport.

Comment: @spiceyokooko Point exactly. I am not comfortable having a tag called [tag:premier-league] (and currently using [tag:epl] for the example above) if there are 20 other premier-leagues in 5 different sports. This question is regarding the proper use of the [tag:premier-league] tag and how, if at all, it should be used.

Comment: I think you're right being uncomfortable with it, and I intensely dislike acronyms and abreviations. I initially though the OP was referring to the European Premier League when in fact it was the English Premier League! It's an awkward one because the 'Premier' league broke away from the primary governing body for English Football, the Football Association (FA) which all the other English leagues are governed by. The Premier league is governed by UEFA (European Football Association)!

Comment: @spiceyokooko Ahh...I did not know that. This is why we have discussions like this on meta, so we can all be on the same page as a community. I will change [tag:epl] and [tag:ipl] to their full name for now. In fact, you can feel free to start a discussion about the use of acronyms/abbreviations (North American usage may be clear -- NFL, NBA, NHL, MLB, etc.) because as you state, their usage is not as clear internationally.

Comment: Do Meta Tags have subcategories under them? Eg Cricket > Indian Premier League or are they flat?

Comment: @spiceyokooko As far as I know, tags are flat. There could be [tag-synonyms](http://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/synonyms), but I don't think that's what we're looking for in this case. Furthermore, some of our tags state, "Questions using this tag should also be tagged with the specific sport in question." Do we want to tag the sport with the league, or is that redundant? Interesting (and useful) concept, though.

Comment: I can see the problem you've got, you're going to end up with a  lot of different meta tags! I agree with English Premier League, but would prefer English Football Premier League if it isn't too long.

Comment: @spiceyokooko It's not much right now, but as you may already recognize, it can become messy. FYI, I started a meta discussion about the [usage of acronyms/abbreviations as tags](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/294/usage-of-acronyms-abbreviations-as-tags).

Answer (score 1):

I have to point out that I tagged my question with [english-premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-premier-league) not just [premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premier-league), as far as I can see the tag is still in its original form (in other words, not edited).

Furthermore there is no European Premier League to be confused with. I do accept the potential confusion between EPL and IPL if one only refers to English Premier League as [premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premier-league). I believe EPL should be as acceptable as a tag as NBA, or NFL is. Likewise I see potential is having tags for other major leagues such as: [la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-liga) (Spain), [serie-a](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serie-a) (Italy) and [1.bundesliga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1.bundesliga) (Germany); similarly [champions-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/champions-league) and [uefa-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uefa-league) for the two major competitions in europe would be acceptable. The motivation behind my opinion is that the regulations governing matches and teams are different in between these competitions.

Bottomline here is essentially that the ones who might not recognize the abbreviation are most likely to be people who would not be able to answer the question in the first place. Considering that any one of the above-mentioned tags should be accompanied with [football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football) tag, anyone who might not feel at home with the abbreviation but still interested in learning about some regulation concerning football would still have enough clue to be drawn into checking the question out.

Comment: I don't agree with [tag:EPL], it is not as commonly used as an abbreviation as NBA or NFL, which are self-explanatory.

Comment: I would have to disagree, EPL is just as self-explanatory as any other abbreviation (which are not particularly self-explanatory, per default).

Comment: You now that on the EPL twitter-account it is consistently called BPL?

Comment: And maybe self-explanatory was not the right word. But NFL and NBA are primarily used to name the competitions, while EPLS in daily life is just called premier-league. But, considering the other topic, I think using an EPL tag with right tag-wiki might solve the whole discussion.

Comment: Good call. I used your tag as an example to illustrate a point...about how tags may get ambiguous.

Comment: I think the acronym EPL is recognized in most football playing nations. The FA tries to market it as BPL (Barclays Premier League) for sponsorship reasons but it has not taken off and the league is still famous and mentioned as the EPL worldwide. Have to agree with posdef in saying this acronym is not ambiguous. However like @Bernhard suggests, editing tag-wiki should help in sorting out this issue.

Comment: @edmastermind29 can't we use tag synonyms for this reason? I checked out the tags page but I guess I don't have the necessary rep to suggest/create tag synonyms

Comment: @posdef [tag:epl] -> [tag:english-premier-league]...I don't see why not.