# Should "wages" tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [wages](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wages) tag, according to the tag wiki, encompasses not only the wages of people, but the financials of sports organizations:

> Questions about financial information in sports. This includes
>   compensation for professional athletes and other employees and
>   revenue/expenses for sports organizations and teams.

The name of the tag has caused some confusion in tagging this question:

[Who benefits from Football Association Fines](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/who-benefits-from-football-association-fines) - [edit history](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/3299/revisions)

Should the tag be renamed to something that reflects the full scope of the tag?

Comment: For future reference, in light of [this question](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/527), tags should be renamed **not** because a user disagrees with the word used. [Tag wiki's should be utilized to understand tag usage](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/).  We transcend among different cultures and languages, so there will be confusion between [football and soccer](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/5) and [hockey and ice-hockey](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/40), but disagreement shouldn't be the only precursor to renaming tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the tag to [finances](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finances), with the same description as the current [wages](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wages) tag has.  [wages](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wages) can be made a synonym of [finances](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finances).

This will better reflect the full scope of the tag.

Comment: I don't disagree, but there are probably many terms that could be used. If the tag wiki scopes financials, perhaps changing the tag name to [tag:finances] eliminates confusion and fully scopes the tag, as you say. See [here](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation) for the first merger of the [tag:wages] tag.

Comment: Tag has been renamed.