# What is the actual use of the tag [performance]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The excerpt of the tag reads like this:

> For questions generally relating to the **(physical, mental, emotional) performance of athletes** in various sports. Most questions using this tag should also be tagged with the specific sport in question.

So I think the tag is not for the overall match performance like in cricket batting performance or bowling performance etc. In other words how a player performed in the match.

Should this type of question be tagged with [performance](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

When you say "batting/bowling" performance, I think about the statistics that portray the objective "performance" (in your terms) of a player. I believe this is what you are referring to as well. This could be covered using the [statistics](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag.

This tag, as stated, relates to the "(physical, mental, emotional) performance of athletes," not in regards to objective statistics, but in regards to energy level, concentration, fatigue, etc.

Thanks for reading the tag. Assumptions are made, and I believe tags need to be read more in order to understand its meaning (eg, bowling the sport vs. cricket bowling). We have had [a request to change a tag name](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/460) simply because [a user didn't like the name of the tag](https://sports.stackexchange.com/revisions/3299/6) (it may be justified, but we are a community and thus, was brought to meta).